# Is there any efficient way to create a random list within a specified boundary?

Tags: python, random

So far, I use the following code for generating a random list with a specified boundary:

```
def initGen(low,upp):
    ini=[]
    for i in range(len(low)):
        ini.append(random.uniform(low[i],upp[i]))

return ini
```

Could somebody suggest a more compact or alternative way to achieve it? The input and output are floats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List comprehension makes the code shorter, if that's what you're after.

```
def initGen(low, upp):
    return [random.uniform(l, u) for l, u in zip(low, upp)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
import numpy as np
low=[5,10]
high=[20,30]
np.random.uniform(low,high)
```

This prints

```
array([ 10.81578449,  26.20810003])
```